# Get Link of an entry from Atom

Tags: php, xml, xpath, twitter

I have this [twitter feed](http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.atom?screen_name=shiplu). I am trying to parse the link to the original tweet. Its the first `entry` in `feed`. I want to fetch the url `http://twitter.com/shiplu/statuses/220057421899505664` inside `href` attribute of first `link` element.

I have used this xpath `/feed/entry[0]/link[@rel = "alternate" and @type = "text/html"]`

But it returns empty string.

Code looks like this,

```
$link = $xml->xpath('/feed/entry[0]/link[@rel = "alternate" and @type = "text/html"]');
```

I think I am almost there. Could anyone correct me what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT*** - fixed the answer based on Vaman comment below

XPath node numbers start from 1, furthermore that feed uses the Atom format that has a namespace - you should do something like this:

```
/atom:feed/atom:entry[1]/atom:link[@rel = "alternate" and @type = "text/html"]
```

where the `atom` prefix is associated with `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom` using:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
```

Comment: I don't think this will work as the `<feed>` node contains namespaces. Namespaces should be considered while forming xpath

Comment: You're right - I did not look at the feed source, i was assuming that there were no namespaces

Comment: Great Information. I just had to add `$xml->registerXPathNamespace('atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');` and your xpath works.

Comment: The fact is I didn't know I have to specify namespace, if the default namespace is defined in the XML already.

Comment: Yeah, that's a common 'gotcha' with XPaths: you have to define the namespace separately AND you have to use always explicit namespace prefixes (there is no 'default namespace' as in XML)

Answer (score 1):

Feed that you pointed out contains namespaces. Xpath expression should take into account namespaces as well. Below is one fully functional expression, though lengthy, which matches the desired href.

`((/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' and contains(name(),'feed')]/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' and contains(name(),'entry')])[1]/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' and contains(name(),'link') and @rel='alternate' and @type='text/html'] )[1]/@href`

Comment: Namespaces are not matter here. Because the element I am accessing are  not in namespaced format (`<name:ns>`)

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im :No. Namespaces does matter. You have a default namespace defined with uri `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom`. Hence all the elements which are not in namespaced format falls under this default namespace. You can get more information on default namespaces at http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp Did you try this expression btw?

Comment: I didn't try it. This expression contains too function call which I really dont want. Check out @MiMo's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This one should work for you: `/feed/entry[1]/link[@rel = "alternate"]`